# Redirect process input and use shell execute

Tags: c#, process, stdout, stdin

Is it possible to redirect *just* `stdin` but also allow `stdout` to be written to the console?

I have a process which starts child processes and needs to read the output of those processes, but also display it in the console. Is it possible? I tried to just create my own console process but I can't write to it unless I UseShellExecute and the purpose is to show the output in the console.

```
protected void startp() {

    Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    psi.Arguments = "/k";

    //Can't redirect output without UseShellExecute = false
    psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = false;

    p.StartInfo = psi;
    p.Start();

    //Can't write to StandardInput with UseShellExecute = true
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("@ECHO OFF");
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo | set /p=Child Process");
    Console.ReadLine();
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
}
```